# XSLT: xpath to get parent element on matched child element name

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am new to xslt. 
I want to get the parent node of matched child node(ends with)

Sample XML:

can have elements before and after parent tag

Here the result should be "parent"
Query: find first parent element name of the child element ends with smile ("endwithsmile")

I could able to get the element which contains ("endswithsmile"), but not ends with . 
ends-with is not working.

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//*[contains(local-name(), 'Identifier')])"/>
```

I also tried using "../" to get parent but didnt work.

Sample xml for above question :::

```
<parent>
  <childendwithsmile>
    <test></test>
  </childendwithsmile>
</parent>    
<parent1>
  <childendwithsmile>
    <test></test>
  </childendwithsmile>
</parent1>
```

Comment: The `ends-with` function is only available in XPath 2.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
//*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - string-length('smile') + 1) = 'smile']/..
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kiril's answer should work, but I prefer this approach that selects a parent based on its child, rather than selecting the child and going back up the tree:

```
//*[*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - string-length('smile') + 1) = 'smile']]
```